# itemize symbol inside math equation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, itemize

```
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{gather}
\scalebox{0.75}{$
\begin{align*}
(\lambda \mid .)\sim N\left(\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i}n_i\theta_i^2+\frac{1}{10}\right)^{-1} \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i} \sum_{\substack{ j=1\\y_{ij}>0}}^{n_i} \theta_i \left(y_{ij}-X_{ij}\beta\right),   
\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i}n_i\theta_i^2+\frac{1}{10}\right)^{-1}\right)
\end{align*}
$}\\
\scalebox{.75}{ $
\begin{align*}
&(\theta_i \mid .) \sim N(\mu_{\Theta}, \sigma_{\Theta}^2) 
\end{align*}
   $} 
\end{gather}
\end{itemize}
 \end{fleqn}
```

How can I put itemize symbol before all equation line?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a single `aligned` environment, introduce an explicit line break right before the first variance term, That way, you no longer need the `\scalebox` stuff.

I would also either get rid of the `\left`/`\right` auto-scaling instructions or replace them with explicit scaling instruction. That's essential, in fact, for the parentheses (or brackets) that enclose the mean and variance terms of the first normal distribution, as `\left`/`\right` pairs are not allowed to span line breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
$\begin{aligned}[t] % use 't' to force alignment with "\item" marker
(\lambda \mid \cdot\,)
&\sim N\Biggl[
 \biggl(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i} n_i\theta_i^2+\frac{1}{10}\biggr)^{\!\!-1} 
 \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i} \sum_{\substack{j=1\\y_{ij}>0}}^{n_i} 
 \theta_i (y_{ij}-X_{ij}\beta)\,, \\
&\qquad\quad 
 \biggl(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i} n_i\theta_i^2+\frac{1}{10}\biggr)^{\!\!-1}
 \,\Biggr]\\[2ex]
(\theta_i \mid \cdot\,) 
&\sim N(\mu_{\Theta}, \sigma_{\Theta}^2) 
\end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the small font inside the equation for this frame. How can I do that?

Comment: @Uddin - You could type `\small` (or `\footnotesize`) after `\item` and before `$\begin{aligned}[t]`. However, the equation fits just fine inside the text block -- why reduce the font size and make it unlikely that your audience will succeed in reading what you're placing in front of them?